# Arduino giga PWM on TIMx with registers

Tags: arduino, stm32

I am trying to use the hardware timer to create a PWM signal. First I created a program using in STM cube IDE using black pill (STM32F411 chip), which works fine. Now I am trying to adapt the code for the arduino giga, which I am programming through arduino ide. The timer initializes but the pin PA7 (D5) is not switching between  HIGH and LOW.
To create the program I used these documents:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h747xi.pdf
https://electroprojecthub.com/blog/stm32-timer-pwm/

I checked all of the registers multiple times and do not see a problem. There are no errors when uploading the code. Here is the code:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  HAL_Init();
  // 1. Enabling The Clock Sources
  RCC->APB1LENR |= RCC_APB1LENR_TIM14EN;    // Enable TIM14 peripheral clock source
  RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;    // Enable GPIOA peripheral clock source
  // 2. GPIO Setup
  GPIOA->MODER |= (0x2UL << 14);    // PA7 Alternate function AF9
  GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= ( 0x2UL << 14 );    // PA7 very high speed
  GPIOA->AFR[0] |= ( 0x9UL << 28);  // AF9 for TIM14 AFR[7] 
  // 3. Counter Mode
  // As the TIM14 peripheral only supports counting up there is nothing to be configured.
  // 4. Timer Timing Parameters
  TIM14->PSC = 15000-1;
  TIM14->ARR = 15000-1;
  TIM14->CCR1 = 10000-1;
  // 5. Configure PWM Mode
  TIM14->CCMR1 |= ( 0x6UL << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos );    // PWM mode 1 6<<4
  TIM14->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;          // Enable preload of CCR1 1<<3
  // 6. Enable Auto Reload Preload
  TIM14->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;    // Enable preload of ARR 1<<7
  // 7. Signal Polarity, CC Output
  TIM14->CCER &= ~TIM_CCER_CC1P;     // Set signal polarity - 0
  TIM14->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;      // Enable CC - On - OC1 signal is output on the corresponding output pin 1<<0
  // 8. Set Interrupt Source
  TIM14->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;    // Setting UG bit does not gen. int.  Only counter overflow generates an UEV if enabled 1<<2
  // 9. Reload The Registers
  TIM14->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;    // Generate an update event 1<<0
  // 10. Enable timer
  TIM14->CR1 |= 1<<0; // enable timer 1<<0
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println(TIM14->CNT);
}
```

Comment: Try adding a delay between enabling the GPIOA clock, and configuring GPIOA. The clock may take a bit of time to start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `GPIOA->MODER |= (0x2UL << 14);    // PA7 Alternate function AF9`

In contrast to 'F4, in 'H7 which is basis of your Arduino Giga, all pins except the JTAG ones are [set as Analog by default after reset](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g70.html), i.e. most fields of GPIOx_MODER are 0b11. By ORing anything you won't achieve the required 0b10 for Alternate Function.

Try

```
GPIOA->MODER = (GPIOA->MODER & ~(0x2UL << 14)) 
   | (0x2UL << 14);    // PA7 Alternate function AF9
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you @wek for your help. I am trying to run multiple timers. I was able to create PWM using timers 12, 13 and 14. Now I am trying to run it also  on timer 15, 16, 17. The timer counts but the PWM signal is not created. As the pins PB8 (D8) and PB9 (D9) are default for I2C1 a cleared the alternate function bits before assigning AF1. Timer 15 uses pin PA3 (D2) so I need to set AF4 according to reference manual (page 91). As the PWM signal is not created I suspect some hidden mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to create PWM using timers 12, 13 and 14.
> Now I am trying to run it also on timer 15, 16, 17.
> The timer counts but the PWM signal is not created.

This is a different question, that's why another answer.

I did not look into 'H7 manual, but TIM15/TIM16/TIM17 tend to have complementary outputs, and as such, they have TIMx_BDTR register and related logic around Break. [You need to set TIMx_BDTR.MOE](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g3.html).

> As the pins PB8 (D8) and PB9 (D9) are default for I2C1
> I cleared the alternate function bits before assigning AF1.

I don't know what does "default for I2C1" mean. Normally, you would read the GPIO chapter in Reference Manual (RM), which details the reset values of all GPIO registers, and act accordingly. If Arduino performs some GPIO initialization behind the curtains, well, that's upon Arduino to document appropriately (or you are not supposed to use Arduino environment for using the module in other than intended way - I don't use Arduino so I don't know what is their take on this issue).

Nonetheless, clearing bitfields before setting some bits of it is a safe bet. However, don't perform it in two steps (i.e. don't read_register-AND-write-read_again-OR-write) i.e. don't use compound &= and |= operators; use a temporary variable or an expression where you read explicitly once and then write once by assigning the result to the register (as in my example in the first answer).

JW

Comment: Thank you it worked.  "default for I2C1"  - according to arduino full pinout https://content.arduino.cc/assets/ABX00063-full-pinout.pdf and https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h747xi.pdf (page 94). Thanks for the additional advice, I will upgrade the code.